# Failed to load bundle Unexpected Token null

Tags: react-native

This is my first ReactNative project [following this tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/165140/react-native-tutorial-building-ios-android-apps-javascript), and I'm running into this issue:

```
 bundling failed: SyntaxError in /Users/wc/PracticeApps/firstapp/PropertyFinder/App.js: /Users/wc/PracticeApps/firstapp/PropertyFinder/App.js: Unexpected token (24:11)
  22 | 
  23 | class SearchPage extends Component<{}>{
> 24 |     export default class App extends Component<{}> {
     |            ^
  25 |     render() {
  26 |         return (
  27 |           <NavigatorIOS
```

I've searched for this error, and haven't been able to find much. What is this error telling me - that the term `default` is null? How can I read this error in the future to debug?

Here is the complete App.js file:

```
'use strict';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  Platform,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  NavigatorIOS,
} from 'react-native';

const instructions = Platform.select({
  ios: 'Press Cmd+R to reload,\n' +
    'Cmd+D or shake for dev menu',
  android: 'Double tap R on your keyboard to reload,\n' +
    'Shake or press menu button for dev menu',
});

class SearchPage extends Component<{}>{
    export default class App extends Component<{}> {
    render() {
        return (
          <NavigatorIOS
            style={styles.container}
            initialRoute={{
              title: 'Property Finder',
              component: SearchPage,
            }}/>
        );
    }
  }
}


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Tutorial that you provide tells:

> Add the following class **below** the SearchPage component

Not **in** the SearchPage component. Javascript does not have subclasses (but Java does).

If you don't know still, where the problem is, please check out this links:

- Javascript classes documentation https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes
- React Component documentation
  https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html